# Child form of invisible parent never being shown?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, invisible

I have a main form, which is invisible and at some point creates a child form. That child form looks like this in designer.cs:

```
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        //this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(255, 147);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(502, 384);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "Form2";
        this.Text = "Form2";
```

and in the main form I'm creating the Form2 as follows:

```
    Form2 a = new Form2(new Point(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2)); //This is the location
                        Thread thtt = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate()
                            {
                                a.CreateControl();
                                a.Show();
                                TimeSpan slept = TimeSpan.Zero;
                                while (!a.Created && slept < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000))
                                {
                                    Thread.Sleep(99);
                                    slept += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(99);
                                }
                                if (!a.Created)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("after 2 sec no creation?");
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //a.Show();
                                    a.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                                    {

                                        a.TopMost = true;
                                        a.Location = new Point(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height / 2);
                                        Cursor.Position = new Point(a.Location.X + 10, a.Location.Y + 10);
                                        a.AddAndAct(minimized);

                                    });
                                }
                                aa = a;
                            });
                        thtt.IsBackground = true;
                        thtt.Start();
```

The problem I'm encountering is, that the Form2 is actually flashing, but then disappears magically. Any suggestions appriciated.

Thanks in advice, Alex

Comment: May I ask why you are creating an invisible parent?  Is the Visible property of the first form actually set to false?  What is the trigger in your code for the parent form to call the code above and create the child?

Comment: the trigger is a hotkey, and the parents Visible is set to false. The parent form is being created, but at some point Hide(); is being called on it, so its no more visible. When the hotkey is called, a event handler is being invoked, which then creates the client.

Comment: Actually, its being closed! I just had a look with EnumThreadWindows, the window shows for 1 sec, then closes without a word. Very weird...

Comment: Hi Alex - I'm going to try to repeat it in a test application.  Meanwhile, what happens if you pop a message box in the form_load event of Form2 (in an attempt to force it to stay open at least as long as the message box).  I should think that would work, until you closed the message box, but maybe I'll be surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex - I think this is your problem:

[How to create a form on its own thread and keep it open throughout application lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369790/how-to-create-a-form-on-its-own-thread-and-keep-it-open-throughout-application-li)

The accepted answer is very true, for I use it in my applications as well, and had forgotten about it.  =)

"You will need to start a message loop on the newly created thread. You can do that by calling Application.Run(form)."